# Proxying 3rd party GUI

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, grails

My issue is the following: I need to incorporate GUI of 3rd party product into the GUI of my product and need to remove some of the 3rd party GUI components on the fly. Thought about using iframe, but can't see how it can be utilized for modification of embedded page. Are there any libraries that could help me with this or the only way to do it is to write the proxy from the scratch?

Thanks,
Mikhail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You could try to use a tool which changes the pages in your browser on-the-fly, for example [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey).
- Another approach is to use to use a scraping library, something like *jsoup* ([others and comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_parsers)).